# How can i get an looping array from this prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am still trying to rebuild an app with prepared statement. In the following case I need an returning array that loops throug the result. How can I do it?!?

```
$page       =   'home';

require($reqcon);

$stmt = $connect->prepare("
SELECT page.alias, page.id, pagel10n.text AS sitetitle, pagel10n.languageCode AS langCode, IF ( lang.translationID IS NULL, lang.`Name`, langl10n.text ) AS langName FROM pages AS page LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS pagel10n ON ( page.translationID = pagel10n.translationID ) LEFT JOIN languages AS lang ON ( pagel10n.languageCode = lang.ID ) LEFT JOIN `l10n-strings` AS langl10n ON ( lang.translationID = langl10n.translationID AND langl10n.languageCode = ? ) WHERE page.`status` = '1' AND page.alias = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $querylang, $page);
$stmt->bind_result($id, $alias, $sitetitle, $langCode, $langName);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements - The whole page is very interesting but please see the section *Fetching results using bound variables* for your question in specific. A smaller example is on http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-result, the *Example #1*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MySQLi documentation on [bind_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

> ### Note:
>
> All columns must be bound after `mysqli_stmt_execute()` and prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`. Depending on column types
>   bound variables can silently change to the corresponding PHP type.

Thus, your code should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $querylang, $page);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $alias, $sitetitle, $langCode, $langName);
while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // your job
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Do not rebuild it using mysqli. You'll waste your life fighting it's unusable interface.
Rebuild it using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("your query goes here");
$stm->execute(array($querylang, $page));
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

now you have a regular array with all the requested data which you can use whatever way you want (supposedly loop over in a template)